# Canvas Clear in Paper.js

Tags: javascript, canvas

Does anyone know the best way to clear a canvas using paper.js
I tried the regular canvas clearing methods but they do not seem to work with paper.js

Html

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" style="background:url(images/graphpaper.jpg); background-repeat:no-repeat" height="400px" width="400px;"></canvas>

<button class="btn btn-default button" id="clearcanvas" onClick="clearcanvas();"     type="button">Clear</button>
```

Javascript/Paperscript

```
<script type="text/paperscript" canvas="myCanvas">
// Create a Paper.js Path to draw a line into it:
tool.minDistance = 5;

var path;
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");

function onMouseDown(event) {
// Create a new path and give it a stroke color:
path = new Path();
path.strokeColor = 'red';
path.strokeWidth= 3;
path.opacity="0.4";

// Add a segment to the path where
// you clicked:
path.add(event.point, event.point);
}

function onMouseDrag(event) {
// Every drag event, add a segment
// to the path at the position of the mouse:
path.add(event.point, event.point);

}


</script>
```

Answer (score 23):

Regular clearing does not work because paper.js maintains a scene graph and takes care of drawing it for you. If you want to clear all items that you have created in a project, you need to delete the actual items:

`project.activeLayer.removeChildren();` works as long as all your items are inside one layer. There is also `project.clear()` which removes everything, including the layer.

Answer (score 4):

In case someone comes looking for an answer with little experience in Javascript, I made a simple example :

1) As Jürg Lehni mentioned `project.activeLayer.removeChildren();` can be used to remove all items inside active layer.
2) To reflect the cleaning you have to call `paper.view.draw();`.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Circles</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="paper-full.js"></script>
        <script type="text/paperscript" canvas="canvas">

function onMouseUp(event) {
   var circle = new Path.Circle({
    center: event.middlePoint,
    radius: event.delta.length / 2
});
circle.strokeColor = 'black';
circle.fillColor = 'white';

}

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    paper.install(window);
    window.onload = function () {
        paper.setup('canvas');
         document.getElementById('reset').onclick = function(){

            paper.project.activeLayer.removeChildren();
            paper.view.draw();

        } 

    };

  </script>      
</head>
<body>
    <canvas style="background-color: #eeeeed" id="canvas" resize></canvas> 
    <input id="reset" type="button" value="Reset"/>
</body>
</html>
```

> CSS :

```
html,
body {
   margin: 0;
   overflow: hidden;
   height: 100%;
}

/* Scale canvas with resize attribute to full size */
canvas[resize] {
  width: 58%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use `project.activeLayer.removeChildren();` for clear entire layer,
or you can add your new paths to group and remove all childrens in group

```
var myPath;
var group = new Group();

function onMouseDown(event) {
    myPath = new Path();
}

function onMouseDrag(event) {
    myPath.add(event.point);
}

function onMouseUp(event) {

    var myCircle = new Path.Circle({
        center: event.point,
        radius: 10
    });
    myCircle.strokeColor = 'black';
    myCircle.fillColor = 'red';
    group.addChild(myCircle);
}


    // connect your undo function and button
    document.getElementById('clearbutton').onclick = btnClear;

    function btnClear(){
        group.removeChildren();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`c.width = c.width; ctx.clearRect(0,0,c.width,c.height);` should be a good catchall if you've not tried it.

Beware however - setting canvas width will reset the canvas state including any applied transforms.

A quick google took me to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/paperjs/orL7YwBdZq4 which specifies another (more paper.js specific) solution:
`project.activeLayer.removeChildren();`

Comment: The above command you described clears the canvas, not the Scene graph. However the second one does work just fine.